# Why is redirecting STDERR to /dev/null done this way?

Tags: io-redirection

This does not make sense to me.

```
wibble > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I think it would make more sense if it was something like this:

```
wibble 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

In other words

```
Commands Output Sendall STDERRORS to STDOUT then SEND it all to /dev/null
```

What is the thinking behind the order of the command redirection `xxx > /dev/null 2>1`?

Comment: You might also find [this explanation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) useful.

Comment: Thanks @rozcietzewiacz that actually explains my question exactly

Comment: There’s an excellent passage in the middle of [that page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055#If_you.27re_still_confused...) on Greg’s Wiki: “If you’re still confused at this point, it’s probably because you started out with a misconception about how FDs work, and you haven’t been able to drop that misconception yet.  Don’t worry – it’s an extremely common misconception, and you’re not alone.  …  Many people think that `2>&1` somehow “unites” or “ties together” or “marries” the two FDs, so that any [subsequent] change to one of them becomes a change to the other.  This is not the case.”

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The redirects are processed from left to right. If you do

```
2>&1 1> /dev/null
```

The first redirect makes `stderr` point to the stream that `stdout` points to at that time (which is your tty essentially). It doesn't make `stderr` an alias of `stdout`.

Then `stdout` is redirected to the bit bucket. The `stdout` redirect doesn't affect the previous `stderr` redirect. `stderr` still refers to your tty.

So:

```
ls file_that_doesnt_exist 2>&1 1> /dev/null
```

will print only the error message on your terminal.

The [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) redirection documentation page mentions this explicitly:

> Note that the order of redirections is significant.  For example, the command

```
          ls > dirlist 2>&1
```

> directs both standard output and standard error to the file dirlist, while the command

```
          ls 2>&1 > dirlist
```

> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, **because the standard error was duplicated from the standard output before the standard output was redirected to dirlist**.

Comment: Yay solves my conundrum. I still think logically its confusing. but i found another part on the same page that is interesting `&>/dev/null` is semantically equivalent to `/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: It should be emphasized that the page you are talking about is part of the ***Bash*** Reference Manual.  It, obviously, describes *bash*.  There are other shells in the world, different from bash, and `&>` and `>&` (when not used in the context `2>&1` or `>&2`, etc.) are bash-isms and are not [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_01).  They should not be used in shell scripts that you want to be portable.