# Redirect the output of a command in `time command`

Tags: io-redirection, time-utility

I am trying to time something using:

```
/usr/bin/time myCommand
```

However, since `/usr/bin/time` writes to stderr, if *myCommand* also writes to stderr, I will get more than just time's output on the stream. What I want to do is, redirect all of myCommand's output to `/dev/null`, but still write time's output to stderr. Using an example *myCommand* that writes to stderr of `ls /nofile`, we see that (obviously) there is no output at all with the following:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ls /nofile 2> /dev/null
$
```

Without any redirection, we see both the output from `ls` (to stderr) and the output from time (also to stderr):

```
$ /usr/bin/time ls /nofile
ls: cannot access /nofile: No such file or directory
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3776maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+278minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

What I want is something that simply produces:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ls /nofile > RedirectThatImAskingFor
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3776maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+278minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using time command in script file. i want time output in stdout instead of stderr. how can i get this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-time-output-to-file-in-linux/33160521

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In ksh, bash and zsh, `time` is a keyword, not a builtin. Redirections on the same line apply only to the command being timed, not to the output of `time` itself.

```
$ time ls -d / /nofile >/dev/null 2>/dev/null

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

To redirect the output from `time` itself in these shells, you need to use an additional level of grouping.

```
{ time mycommand 2>&3; } 3>&2 2>mycommand.time
```

If you use the GNU version of the standalone [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) utility, it has a `-o` option to write the output of `time` elsewhere than stderr. You can make `time` write to the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/time -o /dev/tty mycommand >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

If you want to keep the output from `time` on its standard error, you need an extra level of file descriptor shuffling.

```
/usr/bin/time -o /dev/fd/3 mycommand 3>&2 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

With any `time` utility, you can invoke an intermediate shell to perform the desired redirections. Invoking an intermediate shell to perform extra actions such as `cd`, redirections, etc. is pretty common — it's the kind of little things that shells are designed to do.

```
/usr/bin/time sh -c 'exec mycommand >/dev/null 2>/dev/null'
```

Comment: A couple of follow ups: 1) What does the 'exec' in your last suggestion do? It seems to work without it: /usr/bin/time sh -c 'exec ls /nofile &>./output.dat' 2) Is an "intermediate shell" the same as a "subshell" (which you would get I think using parentheses?). I had been trying things like /usr/bin/time (ls /nofile &>./output.dat) to no avail. 3) What is /dev/tty ? I know tty0 is stdin, tty1=stdout, tty2=stderr, but what about just 'tty'?

Comment: 4) With the /dev/fd3 option, it seems you are saying to write the -o output to 3, then redirect 3 to 2, 1 to null, and 2 to null. Shouldn't that send 3 to null also since the redirections happen left to right?

Comment: @DavidDoria `exec` replaces the shell by the specified program instead of running that program as a subprocess. Some shells perform this optimization automatically when a command is the last one in a script. “Intermediate shell” means just that: a shell that's between `time` and `mycommand`; it is unrelated to subshells. `/dev/tty` is the terminal that the command is running on (it is unrelated to `/dev/ttyNUM` which are physical consoles; you're confusing with file descriptors: stdin is `/dev/fd/0`, etc).

Comment: @DavidDoria *Changing what a file descriptor is connected to* happens from left to right, which has the opposite effect. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23964/why-is-redirecting-stderr-to-dev-null-done-this-way or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections

Answer (score 0):

```
[artur@asus-ux21e ~]$ find /etc/pki/CA/private/
/etc/pki/CA/private/
find: ‘/etc/pki/CA/private/’: Permission denied
[artur@asus-ux21e ~]$ time (find /etc/pki/CA/private/ &> /dev/null)

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Comment: That is not the same 'time' (it is a bash alias I believe). Note that it doesn't follow any sensible redirection rules? $ time &> /dev/null

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

Comment: How about this: /usr/bin/time -o time /usr/bin/find /etc/pki/CA/private/ &> /dev/null; cat time

Comment: Yea I've seen that, but I was more just curious about how to do it without using an internal mechanism like -o.

Comment: @DavidDoria  What is giving you the impression that `time` is a bash alias?  `which time` displays `/usr/bin/time` in CentOS 5.7.

Comment: `type time` will show you: `time is a shell keyword`