# The output of time statistics for command execution

Tags: shell

I would like to ask what the output of time statistics for command execution belongs to (which file description) since it is neither 1(stdout) nor 2(stderr) !
And why so ?

```
#
#
#
# time date 1>/tmp/date_1.out 2>&1

real    0m0.00s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s
#
#
#
# cat /tmp/date_1.out
Mon Dec 10 11:20:36 BEIST 2017
#
# 
#
```

Comment: Related: [Redirect the output of a command in `time command`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126057/65304)

Answer (score 2):

It belongs to neither stdout nor stderr of `date`.  It belongs to stderr of the `time`.  Observe:

```
$ ( time date 1>/tmp/date_1.out 2>&1 ) 2>time.out
$ cat time.out

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

`time` executes `date 1>/tmp/date_1.out 2>&1`.  The output of `time` is not subject to the redirections that are applied to the output of `date`.  This is possible because `time` is not a normal command: `time` is a shell keyword:

```
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
```

Thus, it gets to play by different rules.

Comment: Then，I'd like to know the relationship & rule between shell reserved word and its output redirection！

Comment: @lylklb There is no universal answer for shell keywords.  The answer demonstrates how to redirect the output of `time`.

Comment: Anyone has more explanation or good idea about the relationship & rule for the output redirection of shell reserved word ？！

Comment: @lylklb Are there any specific words that you are interested in besides `time`?

Comment: I have a little understand what you mean,  and I also think there is just only the time reserved word that has a standalone command's output character !