# How do I make an output file for the "time" command?

Tags: linux

I'm sorry if this seems like a trivial question as I'm very new to linux.

Anyway, I need to record the time for executing a shell script I made.

```
time ./executable_file <input_here> > time_elapsed.txt
```

But obviously this only gets the output of the script I made. Any way on how to do this?

update: So what I did was do the GNU version to get an output file for it. It worked now.

Comment: Does this help? [Redirect the output of a command in `time command`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126057/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver yes this is exactly what I needed. I couldn't find it. Thanks!